# how to deconvolution after smooth in python

Tags: python

I have points x and y . How can I deconvolution after smoothing in python.
This is my code

```
import xlrd     
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit    
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d    
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter    
from scipy.interpolate import spline    
from scipy import interpolate    
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from scipy import signal    
    
loc = "C:/Users/A2n/Downloads/1.xlsx"    
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)     
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)     
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)    
x = []    
y = []    
for i in range(sheet.nrows):    
    if(i!=0):    
        x.append(float(sheet.cell_value(i,0)))    
        y.append(float(sheet.cell_value(i,1)))    

x=np.array(x)    
y=np.array(y)   

xx = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(), 1000)   

itp = interp1d(x,y, kind='linear')    
window_size, poly_order = 101, 3    
yy_sg = savgol_filter(itp(xx), window_size, poly_order)    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))    

ax.plot(x, y, 'r', label= 'Unsmoothed curve')    
ax.plot(xx, yy_sg, 'k', label= "Smoothed curve")    
plt.legend(loc='best')    
plt.show()
```

[Output of program without deconvolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd1RO.png)

Comment: We are unable to interpret this code without indentations in Python.

Comment: @pt12lol -  i edit my post .